# Why Am I Getting a Lot of Zeros on the Word Count (i.e. -wc) when Grepping a File (.gz)

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am getting a lot of zeros when counting a string. I need to do this for multiple files. I am trying to do this in a shell script as well. But I do not mind a command that will output the count amount with filename.

This currently works but it is too manual for 90 files:

```
less filename.log.2014-11-01.gz | grep -wc "burgers for 1 dollar"
count: 5678
```

With the command above it works. But when I try to add this to my shell script multiple times and run the script, it returns zeros? This cannot be correct:

```
#!/bin/bash

less filename.log.2014-11-01.gz | grep -wc "burgers for 1 dollar"
less filename.log.2014-11-02.gz | grep -wc "burgers for 1 dollar"
less filename.log.2014-11-03.gz | grep -wc "burgers for 1 dollar"
less filename.log.2014-11-04.gz | grep -wc "burgers for 1 dollar"
```

output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

`less` is an interactive viewer, not a command for extracting gzipped files. Try with `gzcat` or `zcat` instead.

(Yes, there are ways to make `less` run `gzcat` behind the scenes, but that depends on a configuration which is not always available, as you have clearly noticed.)

Additionally, your code would benefit greatly from a simple loop.

```
for log in filename.log.2014-11-0[1234].gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    gzcat "$log" | grep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar'
done
```

I added the filename to each output line for improved usability. But of course, in this particular case, you want

```
gzgrep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar' filename.log.2014-11-0[1234].gz
```

However, some older versions of `gzgrep` did an imperfect job of exposing the full functionality of the underlying `grep` command, so you may need to revert to a loop if you only have a legacy version of `gzgrep`.

Comment: I tried this:
zgrep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar' filename.log.2014-11-0[1234].gz
But  it says "
-bash: gzgrep: command not found"

Comment: Depending on your distro, `gzgrep` or `zgrep` would usually be included in the [`gzip` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=zgrep&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any), but you will apparently need to install it separately, or revert to the loop solution.

Comment: How do I add multiple strings to search the same file for:

Currently:

    #!/bin/bash
    
    for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
        printf '%s:' "$log"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'
    done

Desired result:

    #!/bin/bash
    
    for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
        printf '%s:' "$log"
        echo "count for dollar for dollars"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'
  
        echo "count for pollar for pollars"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'pollar for pollars'
    done

Comment: That's really broad enough to merit a separate question, but briefly, `grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2` or `grep -f file-of-patterns` or `grep 'pattern1\|pattern2'` or `grep -E 'erepattern1|erepattern2'` and also look into `grep -F` if all your patterns are static strings.